# Convert varchar field (LINES) with a decimal value to an INT value

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

What I see:

```
LINES
======
1.0000
2.0000
3.0000
```

What I want to see:

```
LINES
====
1
2
3
```

What I've tried:

```
UPDATE a
    SET a.LINES = CAST (a.LINES AS INT)
FROM #TEST a
```

Comment: The best solution would be to stop storing numbers as characters. Then this becomes a presentation layer issue. The right datatype is crucial...https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type

Answer (score 1):

Use `LEFT()` :

```
SELECT CONVERT(INT, LEFT(LINES, CHARINDEX('.', LINES)-1))
```

Comment: You should also use TRY_CONVERT in order to avoid erroring out if the data can't be converted.

Answer (score 1):

If `Lines` only contains **integers**, then fix the column:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ALTER COLUMN Lines int NOT NULL; --Use NULL is can be NULL
```

Then the value will look *and* be an integer.

Answer (score 0):

If all of the data are convertable to numeric values as in the sample records, e.g. composed only of digits and at most one dot, then using `FLOOR()` function is enough :

```
UPDATE #TEST 
   SET lines = FLOOR(lines);
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=62c98dd491697489b98ef2a049d4dffd)</kbd>